How should I separate high and low voltage in a junction box?
In California I am installing a SPDT relay to activate a circulation pump from my thermostats.
The relay takes a 24v trigger and connects the 120VAC for the pump. The relay is designed to go into standard a knockout of a junction box and the wire leads are color coded for their function.
But this means that I will have high voltage and low voltage entering the same junction box with no partition since the relay leads all emerge from the same knockout. This seems to run afoul of NEC 300.3c which appears to require the same insulation rating for the wiring within the enclosure.
So perhaps they can share the enclosure if I find 18awg wiring with a 600V insulation rating?

That may not be a correct product then. Some of those are made for only internal use.  Others send 120/240V through the KO hole and the low voltage on outside terminals.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica how could this device be safely used then? As I read the NEC I can use it as long as all the wiring entering the box has the same insulation rating

@Matthew, have you considered running Romex in the smallest size available? The wires don't care if you put 120V or 24V on them.

@Matthew yours is not the only application.  It may be intended for equipment where the low voltage stuff is entirely inside the enclosure. But regardless, see labeling and instructions.

This relay is usually part of the furnace.  Not sure why you have to roll your own.  Anyway, there are relays that do this and are knockout mounted and have the 120 and 24V wires on opposite sides. There are ones that mount inside, with the 24V wires sticking out and ones that mount outside with the 120V wires sticking in.   The relay you describe is not meant for what you're doing.

Can you link me an example of a relay you're thinking of? This is the one I'm looking at and it is applicable to my use case. I see them used all the time. https://www.functionaldevices.com/product/rib2401b

https://www.functionaldevices.com/product/CLC212

There is no furnace. It's a boiler and the supplemental circulation pumps are to handle high floor loops getting inadequate flow

@Matthew -- I take it the 120V stuff is in a junction box?

@ThreePhaseEel Yes, it's in a junction box because I am installing it new :) 120V line to jbox, circ pump wired into same box. I want the 24v trigger from the thermostat controller to turn on the pump. Hence the relay

@Matthew try this instead: https://www.functionaldevices.com/product/RIBT2402SBC

@Matthew I'm interested in why you need the pumps. My attic radiators don't bleed well because the 12-to-15 lb autofill valve isn't enough to do it.  But once full, the height of the radiators and the pressure throughout the closed loop doesn't matter, the circulator (there is only one) works very nicely.  It's not a pump it's a circulator.  Maybe your circulator is too small for when all zones are open or maybe the pipes are arranged so circulation favors lower floors.   This stuff is black magic and I'm always trying to understand it better.

The T2402 has two extra control switches you don't need.  Better to keep it as simple as possible. The CLC212 is probably the right one.   There are variants  (NC/NO, dry or reed switch, and more) you might need to look at.

@jay613 it's because if my ground floor calls for heat my 3rd floor is starved. I have plenty of BTU's just that the radiant piping is imbalanced and it's far easier to add variable speed circulators than redo the loops
